# select top row in mysql without using variables

Tags: mysql

First of all, the mysql variables are not working in my system and I don't know why, and I have no access to try to fix it if it was an configuration issue, so I want to try another way to solve my problem without using them.

Lets suppose I have:

```
Table A
id - auto_increment
job_id - integer
other columns

Table B
date - timestamp
event - integer
A_id - integer (with table A id)
```

Basically I want to select every row/columns of table A for one specific job_id, but I need one more column for every row with the more recent event from table B.

I did something like this once using variables in another system, but all my tries without them become unsuccessfull.

Thanks in advance for any tip.

PS:
This IS NOT my question but if someone get curious about my problem with the variables...

After a long time getting wrong results with my tries to solve my problem I did this:

```
select if(@p, @p:=@p+1, @p:=1) as cnt, t.any_column from any_table t
```

and my cnt column is always equal to 1. Maybe I'm tired.... or variables with problem.. if I had to bet I choose the first option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind this is to get the recent date in a `subquery` using `MAX` function and join it bach on tableA and tableB. Try this,

```
SELECT  a.*, c.*
FROM    TableA a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT A_ID, MAX(`DATE`) recentDate
            FROM    TableB
            GROUP BY A_ID
        ) b ON a.ID = b.A_ID
        INNER JOIN TableB c
            ON  b.A_ID = c.A_ID AND
                b.recentDate = c.`DATE`
```